# PHPLIST - Mail sending failed After installation

Tags: email, phplist

I am using  phplist-2.10.10  ,

Installation and everyting is ok. I tested both in test mode and test=0 mode.

Always i get  - "Mail sending failed",Even i added four lists more than 10 members,two templates.

I think the problem is with "SMTP authentication"

What should i edit in "SMTP host and user,password" - in conifg.

My server is lunar pages server and they gave only smtp hostname(I didnt get username or passsword).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution.

The problem is we need to give smtp authentication(username and password)

So in class.phplistmail.php

Remove these conditions

```
   if (!$this->Host || $ip == $this->Host) {
        $this->Mailer = "mail";
#        logEvent('Sending via mail');
      } else {
        $this->Mailer = "smtp";
#        logEvent('Sending via smtp');
      }
```

`$this->Mailer = "mail";`  and just add

So it will always send mail rather than checking smtp.